# Check if a Negative number falls within a range

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, negative-number

I have a code which reads the temperature values constantly and  temperature values will be always negative. How do I write a If condition in C# to check if this temperature falls with in a range of -44 and -46.

I tried with the below code and still the condition passes

```
             if (!Enumerable.Range(-44, 1).Contains(cameraTemp)
              || !Enumerable.Range(-45, 1).Contains(cameraTemp)
              || !Enumerable.Range(-46, 1).Contains(cameraTemp))
```

I also tried with the below code, but some how still the condition passes

```
             if (!(cameraTemp >= -44 && cameraTemp <= -46))
```

Though my temperature value is -45, still the condition passes.

Comment: There is no value which is greater than -44 and lower than -46 same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try following if range is -44 to -46.

```
 if (!(cameraTemp <= -44 && cameraTemp >= -46))
```

when we fall to nagative number like 0 to -1. 0 is greater then -1. Same way -1 greater then -2. So it is bit reverse order.

If you get confuse with this then you have to convert value to absolute value and then apply condition.

To elaborate more.

Following condition

```
1. if (!(cameraTemp <= -44 && cameraTemp >= -46))
   {
        // Some print or logic
   }

If you write condition above way then your logic only execute if temperature value is not between -44 to -46 including -44 and -46. 

  2. if ((cameraTemp <= -44 && cameraTemp >= -46))
       {
            // Some print or logic
       }
    If you write this way then it only execute for value -44 , -45 and -46.
```

Comment: Explaining how negative numbers work might add more value to the response. My two cents.

Comment: If you pass `-45` as `cameraTemp`, are you sure it will enter this condition?

Comment: @SeM it will not. It will not enter for -44,-45 and -46.

Comment: @dotnetstep Am I getting something wrong or OP is asking _"How do I write a If condition in C# to check if this temperature falls with in a range of -44 and -46?"_, which means that it **should** enter the condition?

Comment: All, it was resolved by applying the condition in reverse order :). Thats my bad.This code worked if (!(cameraTemp <= -44 && cameraTemp >= -46))

Answer (score 1):

Or you should try following if you want to enter range `-44` to `-46`:

```
if (cameraTemp >= -46 && cameraTemp <= -44)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've inverted the operators to check temperature

```
if (!(cameraTemp <= -44 && cameraTemp >= -46))
```

`-45` is inferior than `-44` and superior than `-46` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up your greater thans and less thans.  In your second attempt, you can't simultaneously be less than -46 (e.g. that would be -47, -48, etc.) and greater than -44 (e.g. -43, -42, etc.)

```
if (!(cameraTemp <= -44 && cameraTemp >= -46))
```

Answer (score 0):

-46 is smaller than -44 so you have to reverse your condition.

```
if (!(cameraTemp <= -44 && cameraTemp >= -46))
```